# After some idle time images not load from database

Tags: c#, mysql, webforms, bootstrapping

My problem is when I click on the product page (in URL below). It works good but after some idle time on first click on product menu it wont load product images from database to Repeater control.

I am using Bootstrap and not using update-panel.

Please Refer Below Link.
[MySite(See Product Page On First Time And Click After 5 to 10 minute of idle time)](http://bminternational.co.in/BMProduct.aspx)

My ASP.net code is

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrProduct" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="portfolio-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <div class="recent-work-wrap hovereffect">
                                <img id="dtimg1" runat="server" class="img-responsive imggray" src='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' alt="" style="height: 185px!Important;" />
                                <div class="overlay1">
                                    <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                        <a id="aimg2" runat="server" href='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' rel="prettyPhoto">
                                            <h2>
                                                <%#Eval("ProductName")%></h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>
                                            <a id="adtimg1" runat="server" class="preview" href='<%# string.Format("~/BMSubProduct.aspx?pro={0}", Eval("ProductId")) %>'>
                                                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>View Products</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I am just not getting that why on first time it won't load any images.

my C# page code is

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
      DataTable dt = DBMaster.getQueryDataTableSchema(query);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string path = GlobalFunction.getPath(1);
            NoProducts.Visible = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                dt.Rows[i]["ImagePath"] = path + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i] ["ImagePath"]);
            rptrProduct.DataSource = dt;
            rptrProduct.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            NoProducts.Visible = true;
            rptrProduct.DataSource = null;
            rptrProduct.DataBind();
        }
   }
   public static DataTable getQueryDataTableSchema(string query)
   {
    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection con = sq.Open())
        {
            IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            IDbDataAdapter adp = sq.GetAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source);
            adp.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new DataTable();
    }
}
```

and masterpage code in page_load is

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SQLString.Config = myconnectionString;
    }
```

Here `NoProduct => No Products Are Available Right Now.`

I have tried many things like below:

1. `EnableViewState="true"` And  `EnableViewState="false"` both for repeater and             in page also.
2. Change connection string in web.config like

   ```
   name="SQLConStr" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=databasename; Uid = username; Pwd = password; Pooling = false; Connection Timeout = 30"
   ```

Here tried with and without connection timeout and pooling.

**Note**: Using `MySQL` database and using interface to open database connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideal time? Could it be that you mean 'idle'?

Comment: The link you provided get: "No Products Are Available Right Now.". EnableViewState must be true. What do you get in ImagePath? What in "path"? Maybe can a slash miss between global path and path?

Comment: @Emanuele but when click on same link on second time it get load Images..

Comment: @Emanuele And You mean am i have to keep "true" to EnableViewState?

Comment: Can you provide more code? Where c# code is located (OnLoad?)?
We can start form EnableViewState=true which is default.

Comment: @Emanuele ok i have edited my question with some more codes.

Comment: You can try to use ConnectionString directly from web.config or using a static class but remove page.ispostback wraps connection string assignment in master page.

Comment: Where is located the first if(!Page.IsPostBack) ? OnLoad? If you debug, does path variable contains right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EnableViewState="true"`

and try to use

`<asp:Image` and `<asp:HyperLink` controls

instead of

img and a tags with runat="server".

Comment: Thanks for your replay..  Got Solution with below solution. 1). Remove Connection string from master Page_Load and keep that assignment in Master Page_Init. And Change html control to asp control.